# Skype tabbed conversation navigation panel narrow out, how can I resize it?

Tags: skype-for-business, lync-2013

Not sure if it's only within this company, but whenever I have multiple conversations tabulated on a left navigation panel, and if I resize skype window, that navigation panel

[image]

Skype tabbed conversation navigation panel narrow out and putting mouse on the border doesn't give me the feature to resize the width of it
How can I resize it? the only solution has been to close everything and reopen.

Version: Lync 2013 (15.0.4963.1000) MSO (15.0.4963.1002) 32-bit